# Avoiding erratic tiny numbers when working with floating point numbers

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy

It some times happen when I use floating point numbers in c++ and only use numbers as multiples of, say 0.1, as an increment in a for loop, the actual number which is the loop iterators is not exactly multiples of 0.1 but has unpredictably other added or subtracted tiny numbers of the order of 1^-17. How can I avoid that?

Comment: Don't use floating points to iterate?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Don't use *non-exact* floating points to iterate. Increamenting by exact numbers like 0.125 is fine with IEEE 754 binary (as long as you stay in the range with enough significant numbers, of course).

Comment: Don't use floating point numbers then. If all your numbers are multiples of 0.1, just use integers and change your units.

Comment: Read your own question, and then look at the list of `Related` questions to the right (just below the `tagged` list). Please pick any of the ones that seem similar to this one (or a few) and read them. This is a duplicate of so many others it's difficult to pick one to reference.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Most effective way for float and double comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison)

Comment: Just to be clear (for Tarek), this is not an issue with C++ and is not localized to C++. This is a reality of using floating point numbers in any language. The issue at hand is that the decimal number 0.1 cannot be represented by a finite number of binary digits, so it incurs truncation error when stored as a floating point value. A typical example of truncation error in decimal (to help explain the concept) is the representation of 1/3. If I allot you three digits to represent 1/3 you give me 0.333, but that is not the same as 1/3 (i.e., it has incurred truncation error).

Comment: @KennyTM, nothing wrong with your advice except that knowing which decimal numbers are exact and which aren't is too much of a burden for most people. And too often your choice of increment can't be changed; if by coincidence it can be exactly represented it's time to get a lottery ticket, because it's your lucky day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't iterate over floating-point numbers.

The problem is that 0.1 can't be exactly represented in floating-point.  So instead, you should do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    float f = i * 0.1f;

    ...
}
```

Comment: The best part is, because he's adding `0.1` each time, even when he gets to a number that logically should be exactly representable (like `1.0` for instance) there's a good chance he won't be. So a line like `for(float f = 0.0f; f < 1.0; f+= 0.1f)` might end up iterating only 9 times.

Answer (score 7):

Use integers for the iteration and multiply by the floating-point increment before using.

Alternatively find a decimal math package and use it instead of floating point.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [excellent article](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=integersReals2) on the subject of working with floats. There is a discussion covering precisely your example - an increment of 0.1:

```
for (double r=0.0; r!=1.0; r+=0.1) printf("*");
```

> How many stars is it going to print? Ten? Run it and be surprised. The code just keeps on printing the stars until we break it.
>
> Where's the problem? As we already know, doubles are not infinitely precise. The problem we encountered here is the following: In binary, the representation of 0.1 is not finite (as it is in base 10). Decimal 0.1 is equivalent to binary 0.0(0011), where the part in the parentheses is repeated forever. When 0.1 is stored in a double variable, it gets rounded to the closest representable value. Thus if we add it 10 times the result is not exactly equal to one.

I highly recommend reading the whole article if you work a lot with floating point numbers.